# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array Database - Game.cs

Tags: mysql, database

It seems thank you to Phil Allison has has fixed my first issue but my new error is now to do with line 246.

```
                        if (Tamer.DigimonList.Length >= 3) {
                          if (Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null) qry.Add("mercenary3", null);
                                        else qry.Add("mercenary3", Tamer.DigimonList[3].DigiId);
                    }
```

Hello there I am sorta new to this if anyone can give me some decent advice on improving this post or even help me with my issue it will be really appreciated!

The game crashes just after loading into the game but the error seems to be on line 245 which is this below

```
                        if (Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null) qry.Add("mercenary3", null);
                    else qry.Add("mercenary3", Tamer.DigimonList[3].DigiId);
```

**The Error**

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.    at Digital_World.SqlDB.SaveTamer(Client client) in
>   C:\Users\Digimon Master\Dropbox\Digimon Master
>   Project\DMOFrosty'sPost\Server\ServerBuildingSection\DigitalWorld\Database
>   - Game.cs:line 245

**The code**

```
Character Tamer = client.Tamer;
                using (MySqlConnection con = Connect())
                {
                    Query qry = new Query(Query.QueryMode.UPDATE, "chars", new Tuple<string, object>("characterId", Tamer.CharacterId));
                    qry.Add("charModel", (int)Tamer.Model);
                    qry.Add("charName", Tamer.Name);
                    qry.Add("charLv", Tamer.Level);
                    qry.Add("experience", Tamer.EXP);
                    qry.Add("money", Tamer.Money);

                    qry.Add("partner", Tamer.DigimonList[0].DigiId);
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList[1] == null) qry.Add("mercenary1", null);
                    else qry.Add("mercenary1", Tamer.DigimonList[1].DigiId);
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList[2] == null) qry.Add("mercenary2", null);
                    else qry.Add("mercenary2", Tamer.DigimonList[2].DigiId);
                    if (Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null) qry.Add("mercenary3", null);
                    else qry.Add("mercenary3", Tamer.DigimonList[3].DigiId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the Tamer.DigimonList is an array of 3 items? I cannot see where it is initialized. You can make a change check by first checking that the array length is greater or equal to the value before you check null. For instance:

```
if (Tamer.DigimonList.Length >= 3 && Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null...
```

This first checks the length of the array. If it is less than 3, then the other checks are not performed, and should avoid getting an index exception.

Edit: Sorry. You will need to wrapper your code because of the else. So more like this:

```
if (Tamer.DigimonList.Length >= 3) { 
  if (Tamer.DigimonList[3] == null) qry.Add("mercenary3", null);
                else qry.Add("mercenary3", Tamer.DigimonList[3].DigiId);
}
```